# How to proceed after getting black screen when booting Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, reinstall

A few days after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade I got into a login screen loop. I tried to solve it with [this](https://sourcedigit.com/25447-how-to-fix-the-ubuntu-login-loop-problem/). None of the suggestions helped and after the final `sudo apt-get -y install lxdm` I only get black screen while booting. I am using a dual boot laptop (win10, which boots fine) and am able to access grub. When I tried to boot in recovery mode (though I dont really know how to use it) or with older kernel version, I got black screen as well.

How should I proceed? Is it better to reinstall Ubuntu or try to fix it (I dont know how)?

EDIT:
The last thing before the black screen is

```
/dev/sda11: clean, 403200/0536061 files, 7291387/34131712 blocks krenkz login:
```

sda11 is my root partition

Comment: `dmesg | less` in recovery mode, at the Shell prompt will tell you what happened the last boot. note that you will be running `less`so hitting `?` will show you the optional keys to handle the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if you are able to get a shell, so lets try the old good way.

You will need a usb with a live iso of any linux distro, ubuntu desktop will do the job, boot with your live usb into ubuntu desktop and ope a terminal, run the command "lsblk" without the quotes and take not of where your ubuntu root partition is located,lets assume its on the sda2 partition, now you will need to run "sudo fsck -a /dev/sda2" change sda2 with your linux partition, if you have a 3 partition table run the same command for each one of your linux partitions (...sda1, ...sda2, ...sda3, etc.)

If the command detects any problem it will fix it automatically, after the commands reboot and see if this has fixed your problem, if not we will need to boot into single user mode (assuming you can get the system to boot) and fix your display manager.

Please fell free to reply or edit your question accordingly if you need further assistance.

Comment: I ran fsck for both my linux partitions but this didnot correct the problem. I will edit the question with additional info.

Comment: @krenkz that's good, it means the problem isn't related to corapted files, if you try to boot you get a black screen right? if you get the black screen and then press ctrl+alt+F1 you get the tty1 or nothing happens? if you get access to tty1 you can login and reconfigure your display manager.

Comment: yes, i am in tty1

Comment: @krenkz that's good, run the command "systemctl status display-manager.service" it will tell you if the display manager is running, after that run "sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3" change gdm3 with the display manager that the previous command outputted. It will open a menu, select again gdm3 and it should be ready, just reboot.

Comment: @krenkz try "sudo systemctl stop gdm.service" and next "sudo systemctl start gdm.service" this should restart your display manager and let you login. did your install worked and stopped after an update or a config change?

Comment: hey, so gdm3 (after reconfigure, stop, start and even new install) still ends in black screen, but lightdm works fine and after several hours I am happily back at my ubuntu login screen loop. I had been messing with computer name and hostname change, but think that the loop is more connected with Nvidia drivers